# PHP version keeps getting switched from 7.1.1 to 5.4.45 on IIS

Tags: php, iis, matomo

I am installing Matomo on Windows servers, and every time I get to the step in the installation process where the first website details (name, URL, etc.) are added and I click continue, the error screen pops up saying Matomo needs at least version 5.5.9.

It was clearly on version 7.1.1 (which the 1st screenshot shows) the entire time that is how I am able to get all the way to step 6 of the configuration.

Then as soon as I click NEXT at step 6 of the configuration (shown in the 2nd screenshot) I get the error screen shown in the 3rd screenshot.

I have been using Matomo since it was Piwik, and never had issues with the installation until this past summer. I have been trying to install this now for a new site and I have been stuck for a week not understanding what the problem is. I have even copied the web.config from another setup, and that didn't work either.

[image: https://forum.matomo.org/uploads/db1181/original/2X/d/d9ae3d7ce8da161b3eb25b03f58f50658b8a02ca.png]

[image]
<sup>(Click images to enlarge)</sup>

[image]

**Edit:**
I just moved the site from the hosting company I was using to free Azure Hosting. I created an app service and it ran perfectly.

Comment: It stands to reason that Matomo isn't pulling the reported 5.4.45 version of of thin air, so... uninstall it?

Comment: Your server is definitely running 5.4.45: `curl --head matomo.smallstepstogreatness.com` shows `X-Powered-By: PHP/5.4.45`. Not sure where you're getting the 7.1.1 from, perhaps reverse proxying between two servers and only one of them is updated?

Comment: Maybe the system check is using the CLI..

Comment: "Nowadays most web hosts support PHP 5.5.9" is a red flag. The web app version you use was shipped a long time ago, as most hosts today only support 7.1, 7.2 and 7.3, http://php.net/supported-versions.php You should check its vendor documentation to see if you need to upgrade the web app to its latest. Also you can run PHP Diagnostics to see what it says about your IIS/PHP installation https://docs.jexusmanager.com/tutorials/php-diagnostics.html

Comment: @AlexHowansky, I reset PHP back to 7.1.1 and these are the complete list of headers Cache-Control →no-store, must-revalidate
Content-Type →text/html; charset=utf-8
Server →Microsoft-IIS/10.0
X-Powered-By →PHP/7.1.1
X-Powered-By →ASP.NET
Date →Fri, 04 Jan 2019 22:54:24 GMT

Comment: After it gets set.  So the initial check is correct.  It gets changed between step 5 and step 6

Comment: @LexLi my web host supports all the way to 7.1.1 i will see about getting to upgrade to 7.2 or 7.3.  I have matomo up and running on other domain and its fine with the same host.  Interestingly enough their tech support fixed it the 1st time, now they have no idea what the problem and cant seem to find thier notes.  but we wont get into that...LOL

Comment: Can confirm that your header is now reporting 7.1.1. Is it running an external executable to install its own copy of PHP over your existing 7.1.1?

Comment: @AlexHowansky not as far as i know.  but i good question

Comment: @AlexHowansky After installing the matomo in an app service on Azure after the setup the headers are reported back with the header X-Powered-By: PHP/7.2.10.  So it definitely doesn't try to install another version of PHP.  there was something happening on my other hosted server.